# How can I upload the media asset using the Resumable Upload API of Meta

Tags: whatsapp

Can anyone work with "Resumable Upload API" of meta? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload

I have completed Step 1: Create a Session. When working on Step 2: Initiate Upload its return

`{"debug_info":{"retriable":false,"type":"NotAuthorizedError","message":"User not authorized to perform this request"}}`

Can anyone have any idea about this? I cannot get the proper resources to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you've already completed the first step i.e Create a Session , I'll assume you have the Access Token

for people who are stuck on the first step can refer this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/uploads/#overview)

---

now coming to the second step:

1. Access token

Make sure you have the right access token , you can refer this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/uploads/#requirements) to check if you have the right token

2. Send the token

A silly mistake that I made while making a POST request to this endpoint is that I was sending the access token as Bearer

Wrong ❌

```
'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('whatsapp.token'),
    'file_offset' => 0,
]
```

instead send the token as 'OAuth'

Correct ✔️

```
'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => 'OAuth ' . config('whatsapp.token'),
    'file_offset' => 0,
]
```

you can refer the full request syntax [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload#step-2--initiate-upload)